# HTML anchors and CSS: select only some URLs to display in @media print

Tags: html, css

In my print style sheet, I want URLs displayed after most links. So, I have:

```
a:after { content:" (" attr(href) ") ";}
```

For the links where I don't want URLs, I have:

```
a.ignore:after { display: none; }
```

and then I use

```html
<a class="ignore" href="http://example.com">don't show the url</a>
```

This works nicely. For navigation within a page, I have a number of anchors and I'm not sure how to suppress the URLs. Right now, both Safari 5.1 and Chrome 16 print out a O (could be a zero). I've found I can suppress the URLs if I have both an ID and a CLASS in the anchor:

```html
<a id="top_of_page" class="ignore" ></a>
```

but is this OK? While it works, it seems wrong...

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please give us some relevant markup of the links you are failing to suppress in print.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: The links are being suppressed, but I'm concerned about using both and ID and a CLASS in the anchor (last line of code in original).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely have both a class and an ID on an anchor tag without any issues.

Comment: Or on *any* element for that matter. Just make sure not to redeclare each one more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use this CSS:

```
a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ") ";}
a[href^='javascript:']:after, a.ignore:after { content: ""; }
```

This will fix your problem with anchors that aren't links, and also prevent JavaScript links from showing their contents, as well as everything else it looks like you need.